# Map one entity to one viewmodel or to many viewmodels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mapping, viewmodel

I have for one customer entity multiple viewmodels depending on the existing views like Create,Update,Get,Delete. These viewmodels share the same properties up to 75% with the entity.

Should I better merge all the customer viewmodels to one big viewmodel?

So I have to map only and always from one entity to one viewmodel and the way back?
Do you see any disadvantage in flexibility for certain scenarios I have not in my mind now?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, Is your question on MVVM's ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the long run, keeping them separate will be better because while the data contained in each ViewModel may be similar or even identical, the intention is different. For example, the Create and Update ViewModels are certainly similar, but have a few important differences. First, the Create view model usually doesn't have the identity of the entity and having it there may be confusing since it doesn't make sense. Second, if the application supports partial updates, the update ViewModel may be a collection of changes to an existing entity, not the entity as a whole.

If you are striving for [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you can achieve re-usability by means other than sharing the entire ViewModel class. Instead, you can create smaller re-usable components and re-use by composition instead of inheritance. Attempting to coerce a single ViewModel class to fulfill all requirements will be buggy beacause the code is more difficult to reason about. Many times, simple copy & paste gets the job done better than what OOP offers.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, splitting up the ViewModels as you describe makes your code base really clear, as you can make sure each ViewModel is exactly fit for purpose and has no unnecessary properties.  On the other hand, it means that you have more code to maintain - a change to your entity may well mean changes to several ViewModels.

On the other hand, the one big ViewModel approach has basically exactly the opposite pros and cons - less code to maintain, but the ViewModels are less fit for purpose.

There isn't really a right or wrong answer here, you've got too weigh up the pros and cons of each approach and decide what will work best for you.

One sort of halfway approach is to have a single ViewModel for Create/Update, one for Retrieve and one for Delete, as the Create/Update are likely to be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Another, most OO option for you lies in good old inheritance: define common functionality between actions in one class `MyVM` and extend it (inherit from it) as you see fit for different actions: `MyVMEdit`, `MyVMDelete`, `MyVMCreate`, `MyVMList'.

This is the best of both worlds: you only maintain things once, and you extend them to fit precisely to every view.

There is no right approach here, since its not a math, any approach you take that gets job done will get the job done :) But ... *sometimes we carried away from our roots too far* :) its pure good old Object Oriented approach.

If inheritance (or extension) poses any issues (for any reason), you can embed `MyVM` portion inside every `MyVM<Action>` model and achieve the same level of abstraction / functionality balance.

As usual - right tool for the right job.

Hope this will help you.